# Consequences of updating target language from "REL" to "NONE" in publishing target

Tags: content-delivery, publishing, broker

I have a website whose entire content(pages/components) are published to broker database and binaries are published to filesystem.
Now I want to publish the css/js files to file system.  I had updated the cd_storage.xml accordingly and published the pages to test environment.  I can see the files on files sytem but the content is embedded with in  tags.
To remove the  tags i had updated the target language in the publishing target to "None" from "REL". 
I have some dynamic components whose templates are using custom tag libraries to render content.
What kind of issues do we face; if we update the target lanaguage? Does the templates with custom tag library work in the similar way? Is there another way to publish the js/css without  tags instead of target language update?

Comment: Please share your `typeMapping` settings in `cd_storage.xml` and how the css/js files are setup (Component Presentations on a Page or Multimedia Components?).

Comment: Are you using dedicated Page Templates to publish .css and .js files as pages?

Comment: Here is the typeMapping node in cd_storage.xml                                     <ItemTypes defaultStorageId="defaultDataFileData" cached="false">
  <Item typeMapping="Binary" cached="false" storageId="defaultDataFile" /> 
  <Item typeMapping="Page" itemExtension=".css" cached="false" storageId="defaultDataFile" /> 
  <Item typeMapping="Page" itemExtension=".js" cached="false" storageId="defaultDataFile" /> 
  </ItemTypes>

Comment: Hi Philippe, yes i am using dedicated page templates to publish the .css and .js files as pages respectively.

Comment: Below is the list of TBBs included in Css/Js PT. 

1) Read Configuration Items TBB - custom .net tbb to read the configuration component associated with publication.
2) Generic Output DWT - simple DWT TBB - it contains DWT code to iterate over components and render the presentation.
3) Resolve Js Images In Output TBB - This resolves the images referred in javascript.
4) Resolve HTML Images In Output TBB - This resolves the images in HTML.
5) Cleanup Template - out-of -box TBB.

Answer (score 2):

You will need REL for any other Tridion delivery-side functionality like dynamic linking or embedded component presentations.

The issue is likely with your templates. If you're creating the CSS or JS as Component Presentation on a page, try `Plain text`in the Component Template Output settings.

Edit: removed the HTML options to avoid confusion. These are *separate* Output Format options:

- HTML Document
- HTML Fragment
- Plain Text

Comment: Yes Alvin, We are using TextBlockCT, whose output format is "Html Fragment" in the CT settings.  We do have certain dynamic components, whose templates are using custom tags like <t:dynamicContent Publication="@@Component.Publication.ID@@"... these tags are interpreted by delivery side custom logic.  Please suggest in these cases we should use "REL" as target language?

Comment: If you're not using the custom tags for CSS and I don't see why (or even how), just set your output to `Plain text`. You should be able to use Template Builder to see the difference.

Comment: When we test the PT and CT in template builder we dont see the <tcdl> tags, but when I publish to the target(whose target language is REL) it is publishing with <tcdl> tags.

Comment: Is your Component Template dynamic? The Page Template would try to add references for embedded dynamic Component Presentations based on the REL setting (outside of template builder).